# How to fix OOM error from following code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here, I am implementing a VGG-19 variant code, that is providing an error as OOM, how do I fix it?

The code environment has been created in Google Collab, please instruct how may I use GPU resource? the GPU resource already connected in the created environment, just inform me how to write the code to access it?

The Python Code:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img, img_to_array
from PIL import Image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img, img_to_array
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
import csv


src_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/CASIA_B90PerfectCentrallyAlinged2_Optical_Image/'
train_imgs = []
train_labels = []
test_imgs = []
test_labels = []
subjects = os.listdir(src_dir)
numberOfSubject = len(subjects)
print('Number of Subjects: ', numberOfSubject)

batch_size = 4
num_classes = numberOfSubject
epochs = 40
#178, 256, 1
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(48, 48, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=1, padding='valid'))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=1, padding='valid'))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=1, padding='valid'))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=1, padding='valid'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()


opt = keras.optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.001)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/GEINet_and_PEINet/VGG19_layer_1_less.py", line 48, in <module>
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 182, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 463, in __call__
    self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 895, in build
    constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 279, in add_weight
    weight = K.variable(initializer(shape, dtype=dtype),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/initializers.py", line 227, in __call__
    dtype=dtype, seed=self.seed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 4357, in random_uniform
    shape, minval=minval, maxval=maxval, dtype=dtype, seed=seed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 5686, in random_uniform
    shape, minval=minval, maxval=maxval, dtype=dtype, seed=seed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py", line 296, in random_uniform
    shape, dtype, seed=seed1, seed2=seed2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_random_ops.py", line 724, in random_uniform
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 6653, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[991232,4096] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:RandomUniform]
```

Comment: You should reduce the number of neurons in both Dense layers, 4096 is too much, maybe use something like 128-256.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not using the GPU, it is that the GPU ran out of memory. It is probably because the network size it too big to handle.

please note that your input is of size `48x48x1`, which means that the output of the last Conv layer(after 4 Pooling steps) is of size `3x3x512`. This layer is connected to a Dense layer with 4096, which means it has `3x3x512x4096` parameters. Then the last layer is additional 4096 neurions, which means additional `4096x4096` parameters. In total you have more than 36M parameters only in the last 2 layers. Then you connect it to the final layer in the size of number of classes, which is additional `4096xnum_classes` parameters (which may be a lot, that depends on the number of classes you have).

So first try to reduce the number of neurons in the Dense layers, and in addition you maybe use to mach filters in your last convolution layers. A typical size of an "embedding" vector which uses for the final linear classification is 128-512, depends on the problem and the given data.